# how to add uipickerview as as subview to mainview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, subview, addsubview, uipicker

I have one application in which when user clicks a button i want to open uipickerview as as subview to main view and after user selects an item it should be  removed from main view.(drop down kind of functionality).For that i have written code as below:

```
-(void)showPrefPicker:(id)sender
{


   UIView *subView=[[UIView alloc] init];
   subView.frame=CGRectMake(180, 120, 150, 150);
   pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(190, 130, 100, 100);
    subView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [subView  addSubview:pickerView];
    [self.view addSubview:subView];
    [pickerView release];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"selected object is %@",[arraypref objectAtIndex:row]);
    //[pickerView ]
    //mlabel.text=  [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arraypref count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arraypref objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

but is only showing subview in the main view not the pickerview.how can i do that any tutorial or source code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you use

to hide

```
pickerview.hidden=YES;
```

to show

```
pickerview.hidden=NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `frame` of the `pickerView` as

```
pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code `subView.frame=CGRectMake(180, 120, 150, 150);`
and  `pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(190, 130, 100, 100);`

picker view is a subview of your 'subView'

here pickerview's frame starts out of bounds of subview ie origin x is 190. but the width of the subview is only 150.

so the correct code is

```
pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

since pickerview is a subview of a custom view. it should be in the frame of its parent view.